# Can't connect to tor website through python

Tags: python, tor

I want to parse an onion website with python, came up with that code:

```
import requests

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5://localhost:9150',
    'https': 'socks5://localhost:9150'
}
url = 'http://sblib3fk2gryb46d.onion'

print(requests.get(url, proxies=proxies).text)
```

Gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socks.py", line 851, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socks.py", line 497, in _negotiate_SOCKS5
    self, CONNECT, dest_addr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socks.py", line 565, in _SOCKS5_request
    resolved = self._write_SOCKS5_address(dst, writer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socks.py", line 621, in _write_SOCKS5_address
    socket.AI_ADDRCONFIG)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Works just fine with clearnet websites. Tor is opened, I use mac os. 
I've tried a few various options, this one is the only one that is working so far(at least i managed to connect through tor to clearnet)

Maybe someone did smth like that before and can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve DNS and also be able to connect to .onion addresses, you need to use the `socks5h` protocol to tell requests to resolve DNS over Tor.  The example above is just `socks5` which means it is trying to use your regular DNS resolver to resolve the .onion address which will not work.

To fix, change your `proxies` to:

```
proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://localhost:9150',
    'https': 'socks5h://localhost:9150'
}
```

Also, for future readers, port 9150 is used by Tor browser bundle.  For using the Tor daemon, try port 9050.